# What does « nombre de lits aux permit means? »

Tags: traduction

I was looking at news regarding pandemic and saw “lits aux permit” in « % de résidents sur le nombre de lits au permits »

What does « nombre de lits aux permit means? »
Is it like number of people infected over total number of people?

Comment: C' est "'lits autorisés au permis".

Comment: What does it mean?

Comment: Copy-paste the sentence and give more context. You quoted the same sentence fragment three times, but spelled it differently each time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better if you provide the link with the exact article.
Not native speaker but I think it is:

> Lits (autorisés) au permis

and it means the number of beds that a hospital (or another sanitary establishment) is authorized to have.

So

> % de résidents sur le nombre de lits au permis

is the ratio of citizens over this particular number (counting several hospitals of a town for instance).

See here for example:

https://m02.pub.msss.rtss.qc.ca/M02SommLitsPlacesProv.asp

PS I add here Greg's useful comment:

*I concur with that, it is also the definition I have found [here](https://iucpq.qc.ca/contribute_documents/R8_repartition_lits_2012-06-19.pdf)*

> LITS AU PERMIS : correspond au nombre de lits alloués par le ministère de la Santé et des Services sociaux.

*Note that it seems to be a Quebec administrative term, if you look up the term on Google, all results are links to Canadian websites (as a Belgian speaker, I also had the feeling this should be the meaning, but I had never heard or read it before).*

Comment: I concur with that, it is also the definition I have found [here](https://iucpq.qc.ca/contribute_documents/R8_repartition_lits_2012-06-19.pdf) LITS AU PERMIS : correspond au nombre de lits alloués par le ministère de la Santé et des Services
sociaux. . Note that it seems to be a Quebec administrative term, if you look up the term on Goggle, all results are links to Canadian websites (as a Belgian speaker, I also had the feeling this should be the meaning, but I had never heard or read it before).

Comment: @Greg: Thanks for this comment. I added it as a nota bene.